# Request Sharepoint 2007 list from SSRS 2005

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, reportingservices-2005

as the title says i'm trying get some list items from my sharepoint website into my SSRS 2005 report. I tryed to folow and adapt some tutorials for SSRS 2008 like this one : 
http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/step-by-step-consuming-sharepoint-lists-data-in-the-ssrs-reports/
The thing is that I get stuck int the 6th step when I try to validate my query. I tryed to pass some queries that i post below:

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems
</SoapAction>
<Method Namespace='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' Name = 'GetListItems'>
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name='listName'>
<DefaultValue>EraDemandes</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name='rowLimit'>
<DefaultValue>100</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name='query' Type='xml'>
<DefaultValue>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
        <Value Type='Integer'>1016</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name='viewFields' Type='xml'>
<DefaultValue>
 <ViewFields> 
  <FieldRef Name='Title' />
    <FieldRef Name='ID' />
 </ViewFields>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name='queryOptions' Type='xml'>
<DefaultValue>
<QueryOptions>
   <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
   <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
</QueryOptions>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces='True'>*</ElementPath>
</Query>

    <Query>
      <SoapAction>http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems</SoapAction>
        <Method Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" Name="GetListItems">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter Name="listName">
              <DefaultValue>Liste des Demandes</DefaultValue>
            </Parameter>
          </Parameters>
        </Method>
      <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">*</ElementPath>
    </Query>
```

I tryed to remove / modify all the parameters without succes. I'm realy not familiar with SSRS so plz go on and ask every question you need.
I have few question myself:

- On the 2 queries i used 2 differents name for the list: "EraDemandes" is the name I got in my URL when i'm accessing my list through sharepoint and "Liste des Demandes" is the name of the list in Sharepoint. I beleive that in sharepoint there is 2 name, a display name and a sharepoint name. Which one should i use ?
- My root Sharepoint Site collection is `'http://m-epderaqua/default.aspx'` and the list I want to casses are on all the subsites from this collection (`http://m-epderaqua/ERA73/default.aspx or http://m-epderaqua/ERA38/default.aspx`). Which web address should I use in my datasource ? Should i use many datasource (like one for each subsites) ?

Help plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell why but it's just working perfectly fine right now. I suppose the maintenance team did somthing during the week-end but I don't know what...